# If property holds for sample in this space does it hold almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of coin tosses $B = B_1, B_2, \dots$, which are not assumed to be neither fair or independent. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all infinite binary sequences, and let $T : \mathcal{B} \to \{0, 1\}$ be a discrete random variable. If $T(b) = 1$ for any sequence $b \in \mathcal{B}$, does it follow that $\mathbb{P}(T(B) = 1) = 1$?

**Attempted argument:** Let $(\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be the probability space associated with the random coin toss experiment above. Then

$$\mathbb{P}(T(B) = 1) = \mathbb{P}(\{b \in \mathcal{B} : T(b) = 1\})$$

and since $\{b \in \mathcal{B} : T(b) = 1\} = \mathcal{B}$, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(T(B) = 1) = \mathbb{P}(b \in \mathcal{B}) = 1.$$

Is there something wrong with this? Does it qualify as a rigorous argument? A part of this that I am a little uneasy about is whether there exists a well-defined probability space $(\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ for this process.

Comment: Yes, in this case $T(B)$ is a constant random variable that is 1 surely, so $P[T(B)=1]=1$.